# I can't type anything on my SSH terminal

Tags: ssh

Is there something that I may have switched off unknowingly that now isn't allowing me to type/enter my password on Secure Shell? If yes, then how do I 'undo' it?

Comment: Your password will not show up on your screen, this is a security feature. Even though it doesn't APPEAR to type anything, just type your password and press enter.

Comment: You may actually be typing... It just doesn't show as a cursor or characters. Is the whole shell unresponsive, or just the password?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are typing your password you are not going to see anything like:

```
password: *****
```

You are going to see something like this:

```
password:
```

Type it and then press enter. Does this allow you to enter?

Comment: If my answer helps you, mark it as answer pleas! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On many SSH apps, password typing does not display any character, so that someone who looks over your shoulder cannot see the number of characters of your password. This might actually work as intended. Just type your password normally and hit enter